# android-support-v7-appcompat нет класса AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-app-compat-activity

Нет класса  `AppCompatActivity` в библиотеке *android-support-v7-appcompat*. Где скачать с классом  `AppCompatActivity`?

Библиотеку я смотрю в %AndroidSDK%/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs

Comment: Конечно же он там есть. Добавьте в вопрос информацию, которая поможет воспроизвести вашу проблему, потому что кроме вас с таким, кажется,  никто ранее не сталкивался.

Comment: @pavlofff возможно нету, файл создан в 2015 году. Возможно тогда ещё небыло AppCompatActivity
Нужно проверить

Comment: Нужна библиотека с классом AppCompatActivity и другими...

Comment: @pavlofff Посмотрите, пожалуйста,  у себя библиотеку. Откройте её через архиватор и поищите класс. Если класс у Вас есть, то Загрузите мне эту библиотеку

Comment: он есть **во всех библиотеках** appcompat. Что заставляет вас использовать библиотеку 2015 года и устанавливать ее вручную, что мешает вам просто указать зависимость в gradle для последней версии? Конечно же я (и никто в здравом уме) не будет разархивировать библиотеки поддержки. Для того, чтобы вам можно было помочь, опишите в вопросе как можно подробнее, какие именно вы выполняете действия, чтобы получить такой невероятный результат, как отсутствие одного из основных классов

Comment: @pavlofff я смотрю классы в библиотеке поддержки. %AndroidSDK%/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs. Если вас не затруднит потратить 1 минуту, то пожалуйста посмотрите, у Вас есть в библиотеке нужный класс? У меня есть ActionBarActivity, но нету AppCompatActivity. Через Android SDK Скачал библиотеку поддержки всю

Comment: Если вас не затруднит, посмотрите, какая  у вас библиотека поддержки скачана. У меня ревизия `23.0.3` A android support repository 47

Comment: Хорошо, я повторю: Что заставляет вас скачивать самому и использовать библиотеку 2015 года, устанавливать ее вручную, что мешает вам просто указать зависимость в build.gradle для последней версии?

Comment: @pavlofff Мешает наверное Андроид СДКей. Это он не выкачивает, наверное. Вообще вопрос не в том что мне мешает, А почему нету класса, и гдескачать нормальную библиотеку. Вообщем нужно найти проблему, мешающую скачать библиотеку! Зависимость указать ничто не мешает. . Вообщем помогите плиз найти способ заказать библиотеку

Comment: Дело в том, что вы делаете какую то хень, которую никто кроме вас не делает, поэтому проблема не в том, чтобы посмотреть, что у меня, а в том, чтобы вы больше не делали так, как не нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы добавить поддержку библиотеки *AppCompat* нужно на этапе создания нового проекта на экране мастера *Configure Activity* отметить чекбокс *Backwards compatibility (AppCompat)* - обратная совместимость:

[image: scrn]

Если по каким то причинам сделать это не удалось, то поддержку библотеки можно добавить позже.

Через мастер:

*File -> Project Structure* или сочетание клавиш *CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + S* или значок на панели инструментов

[image: scrn]

Далее, выбираете ваш модуль (цифра 1 на скриншоте), нажимаете вкладку *Dependences* (цифра 2 на скрине), затем + (плюс)  в правом верхнем углу (цифра 3 на скрине) и там в выпадающем списке *1.Library Dependency* (цифра 4 на скрине)

[image: scrn]

появится диалог поиска библиотеки, куда в строку поиска пишем то, что хотим добавить в зависимость (appcompat), после нажимаем Enter на клавиатуре для начала поиска, выделяем нужную библитеку в окне ниже и нажимаем *OK*, чтобы закрыть диалог и применить изменения, затем *OK* мастера *Project Structure*

[image: scrn]

Пройдет синхронизация и библиотека будет подключена.

Так же можно добавить вручную:

В дереве проекта открываете файл *build.gradle* модуля проекта и в секцию *dependencies* пишите зависимость:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
}
```

где *27.0.2* - версия библиотеки, она обычно соответствует последней актуальной (посмотреть версию [можно здесь](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v7-appcompat)). В правом верхнем углу появится надпись-ссылка *Sync Now*, нажимаете на нее для синхронизации проекта

[image: scrn]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сейчас проверю)

Comment: Работает, загрузка..